# Differences between a function of lag and a function of time

Tags: time-series, lags

I start learning time-series analysis. I started by a tutorial, and found that a stationary process has two conditions:

1-The mean must be constant.

2- Covariance must be a function of lag not a time.

I do not understand the second condition, specifically, What is the difference between a function of a time and a function of lag.

Could you please help me with this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autocovariance function for a random process (call $X_t$) is $r(t,k)=\operatorname{cov}(X_t,X_{t-k})$. This is a function of two parameters. One is the time-lag, i.e. $k$, and the other is the actual time instant, $t$. In stationary processes, this function depends on only the lag, i.e. $r(t,k)=r(k)$.

Sometimes, you can see an alternative form: $r(t_1,t_2)=\operatorname{cov}(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})$, which is basically the same thing. In this case, if the auto-covariance function depends on only the lag, $t_1-t_2$, it satisfies the second condition.